# apt-proxy replacement/alternative on Debian

Tags: debian, apt

I missed that [apt-proxy is not available](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt-proxy&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) anymore.

What are my alternatives?

Google didn't give me anything useful expect years old stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [apt-cacher-ng](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-cacher-ng) for that. If I need a full mirror copy I tend to use [reprepro](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/reprepro). apt-p2p may be a good alternative if you just want distributed downloads.

Comment: Up and runnings, basic operations seems to work (used it as a proxy for installation). I read the docs and expected `find /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/` to list the downloaded packages but I only find a handfull stuff like "Release" files. Do I need anything special to have *.deb files stored there?

Comment: I don't have the time to check ATM, but AFAIR you don't. have to do anything special. The debs should land in the various pool subdirectories without any special configuration.